# How to get Image from resource project

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'have this package on my project:

ProjectName : Gestore

---View (Folder)

------Resources (Folder)

---------Images (Folder)

------------immagine1.png

---DatiAnagraficiPageView.xaml

Now I would like to create programmatically an Image, so I try to write this code but it not found. THe code is:

```
System.Windows.Controls.Image img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Resources\Images\immagine1.png"));
```

I have an exception because the control not find a image.

Can we help me?

I think the error is in the code "Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()"

Comment: What does `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` return?

Comment: It returns "C:\\Users\\michele.castriotta\\Source\\Workspaces\\Omniacare\\software\\exercise platform\\Gestore\\Gestore\\bin\\Debug"

Comment: That returns the path to the `bin` directory... not so useful in this case. Please see the [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that immagine1.png is a resource you should be using [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx), something like

```
new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Gestore;component/View/Resources/Images/immagine1.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() doesn't give you the path where you are calling from but where your executable is executed from.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

try

```
System.Windows.Controls.Image img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage(new Uri("@View/Resources/Images/immagine1.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            img.Source = bm;
```